# d3.js margin convention

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Please see the margin convention as described [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3019563)

Chart only: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/3019563/

Two issues

- If I download the html file from gist ([link](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/3019563/raw/b163f911d8a1c6430930548024d35934bba35a52/index.html)), I get the below view (Google Chrome Version 26.0.1410.43 )

[image]

There is no border around the svg, and the axis line/path is not shown. I am mainly surprised by the lack of axis path as it is within the svg container. What could be wrong?

- As shown in the image, the arrow at top-left corner indicates a `translate(margin.left, margin.top)`. But, I guess it is `translate(padding.left, padding.top)`. Margin is the rect between the origin and svg element. Is it a mistake?

Comment: It is displayed correctly in my chrome (same version as yours). Have you tried zoom in?

Comment: +1 @polybios indeed. cmd+0 (zoom to default) solved first issue. Thanks again. Now curious about 2nd.

Comment: re: your second question, the convention is to set the margin on the inner `g` element, and translate that. Don't think of the padding found in the HTML box model.